# How to create a Material in google Classroom

Tags: google-classroom

I am a teacher. I need to upload content(material) in my google classroom programmatically. The documentation gives the method to upload an assignment but not a material. My automated workflow is stuck because of this reason. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You would use the courses.courseWorkMaterials REST endpoint:

https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWorkMaterials